# How do you navigate to a users show page with devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, show

Like the title says, I am using devise. I want to navigate to /users/1 or whatever the current_users path is. When I try `link_to(current_user.name, user_path)` I just get an error.
**undefined local variable or method `user' for #<#:0x00000101d2dfc8>**

Am I not using the right path? Do I need to route it or something?

Also, this goes with the first, how would i navigate to a different users show page(not the current user)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with devise, but I'd be surprised if devise differed from Rails conventions. You need to pass in the user to the route helper: `link_to(current_user.name, user_path(current_user))`

Answer (score 3):

You will need to to three things to get the view you want because devise doesn't provide the standard user routes.

1) Create a route in config/routes.rb.  Devise doesn't provide a standard route, and in my experience rake routes just confirms this.  I've used:

```
match '/users/:id', :to => 'users#show',    :as => :user,         :via => :get
```

with mixed success

2) Create a user controller with the show section appropriately filled out

3)  create a view file:  user/show and add the parts you want to show.

Comment: how can I make it so that the url isn't /users/:id but just / and then like the user object or something. I don't really like just /users/1

Comment: For devise, there isn't exactly a users controller... where should I put it? I have registrations and sessions controllers, can I use those?

Comment: controllers always go in the controllers folder.  You will need to create it.

Answer (score 0):

What helped for me was to add the @ before user in "routes.rb":

```
"match 'users/:id' => 'users#show', :as => @user"
```